# How to increase or decrease button icon size in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Though I have seen a lot of code but i am unable to reduce the size of the icons

```
.button-icon  {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button class=" button button-icon ion-android-refresh"</button>
  <button class="button button-icon ion-chatbox"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry,I cannot.